# Can we start burninating or synonymising [initalization]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

EDIT 3:

After @JDB has pointed out [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279262/what-should-we-do-with-sets-of-answers-that-are-actually-polling-options) link in the comments, I have been enlightened as to the polling approach of pasting answers and asking people to vote on them is not a good one. Hence, I am deleting one of the answer, and only keeping the one in which I share my views as to what should be done with the matter at hand. In case you have more points, or a different reasoning altogether, feel free to write them down.

---

EDIT 2:

Since there are two ways to deal with this tag, I have added each one of them as an answer below. Feel free to vote on the one you think is the correct choice. This way we can easily see what the consensus is.

---

EDIT 1:

Now that we see that this is a typo of [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization) (which has 6K+ questions), I am not sure if [initalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initalization) should be marked as a synonym for [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization), or burned altogether (since it is wrongly spelt). Views?

P.S.: I can't submit a synonym request due to the "at least 5 upvotes rule". And I also don't want to use the hack of editing one of my post (which has 5 or more score) to add the tag and then suggest a synonym. It isn't ethical IMO.

---

I came across the tag [initalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initalization). It has 57 questions. IMO, the tag isn't powerful enough to independently represent a question, it has to depend on other language tags for closure.

Moreover, there is no usage guidance and tag wiki for the same.

Is it worth burninating this tag?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: I edited you post you where link to another tag initalization, which one is it..

Comment: Nice typo. [tag:initalization] (57 questions) vs [tag:initialization] (6k4 questions) (see the missing `i`). At least make the former a synonym of the latter then.

Comment: Whoa. What a typo!

Comment: Title suggestion: "Can we start burninating or synonymising [initalization]?"

Comment: @AndrewMorton feel free to edit :)

Comment: Reinitialize [initalization]

Comment: Please DO NOT add yes/no posts to your discussion question. See [What should we do with sets of answers that are actually polling options?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279262/191410)

Comment: The [initalization] of burnination.

Answer (score 47):

I see no point in having a tag that is misspelled, and can't see it ever being a valid tag either.

Comment: Agreed. But it still exists. Shouldn't we clean it up somehow?

Comment: @CinCout Hopefully a mod can merge the tags.

Comment: I once read a burnination request about a typo that stated it should be made a synonym, because at some point others will do the same typo and may therefore recreate that tag. But that could go out of hand. Maybe we should have spelling corrections for entering tags

Comment: Or maybe we should have a very steep rep requirement before you are allowed to create tags. Most of the posts on meta is about stupid tags, so clearly the current system is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker there are warnings that are meant to prevent typo-ed tags. If the users are willfully ignoring those (blindly clicking OK,ACCEPT,OK,OK,CONTINUE) then we are having another kind of problems.

Comment: Generally, I agree 100% with this whole thread. A misspelled tag shouldn't exist. Hypothetical question, though: What if someone releases a framework with that as its name?

Comment: @Moshe initialization-framework?

Comment: Just to spite you, I'm going to create a beautiful language that everyone loves called `initalization`.

Comment: @Moshe It would confuse the hell out of everyone and is probably a very, very, very bad marketing move.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case a synonym would be best, as that way the questions don't fill up the front page with the edits etc.   Looking at [Google Trends](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore#q=initalization), it seems to be a common enough misspelling to give some long term benefit to a synonym.

Answer (score -8):

A Stackoverflow employee just needs to rename it [initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialisation)—which is the UK spelling—and then a mod will mark it as a synonym of [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization).