# How many new tags are prevented by the tag creation warning?

Tags: support, statistics, tag-creation-process

[This happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897/213575), and two years later there's no stats about the efficiency of this. Does it exist? Does it need a blood sacrifice?

Basically, I want to know how many burnination requests this has prevented.

Comment: Seems a good feature to me, typos are easy to make and making new tags is rare.  I think I've made a new tag once, and the warning has helped a few times.  That's empirical.

Comment: I think you should post this on meta se

Comment: @Yvette no, because the data I'm interested about is specific to SO, since SO tends to be a host of [crappy tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)

Comment: I am not sure that they collected data on the "go back" button from that interface, and that makes me skeptical the statistics are available here. I wouldn't mind seeing them if the numbers were present though. Certainly interesting.

Comment: @TravisJ there are, since there's a GET call with the following: `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/new-tags-warning?tags=jadajadapunpun&_=1463097404810` so, checking should be possible

Comment: It's prevented me from accidentally creating a new tag a couple of times in the last week or so. I'm guessing it's quite effective at preventing typos from creating new tags.

Comment: @RossRidge yeah, but in this era where the average user just click "OK", "Continue", "Accept" blindly, we need to be skeptical.

Comment: Sites also ban users from creating tags from mobile sites. That may also decrease the rate of bad tag creation.

Comment: Definitely not this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322823/2912665

Comment: So did the buttons eventually get changed so that "yes I want to create a tag" is small and hard to find? I hope so...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It's time for a new process around tag creation: Tags should be reviewed before they are created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404893/its-time-for-a-new-process-around-tag-creation-tags-should-be-reviewed-before)

Comment: @Henke nope, it doesn't. I'm asking for information, not changing the process. Mine can only be answered by employees.