# What is the process for deleting new tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

I'm new to moderator tools, and just noticed this [cie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cie) tag show up with a single question. On the surface this seems very meta, and there is only one question.

Before going into the [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) process, I would like to know if there is a special protocol for managing the creation of new tags. I feel that policing or verifying the validity of new tags is generally going to lead to less moderator intervention than it might later.

I have reached out to the OP as the first step. This seems to me like a reasonable start, though, if I had the power and a bit more credentials behind me, I would be inclined delete it on the spot and remove the reference.

Having just read over it, I feel that this post is the best proposal in this space: [It's time for a new process around tag creation: Tags should be reviewed before they are created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404893/1690217), but I would be happy enough to see voting and flagging added to tags... *Watchers* isn't the best comparison to voting, and doesn't help us when a tag has just been created. Of course, there aren't any subscribers yet.

At this stage I am mainly looking for guidance. I feel like I should be flagging the tag, but that isn't an option. Should I just flag the post? This makes some sense, but I am not an expert in the subject domain, and the post itself seems straightforward and unfair to attract moderation intervention on its record.

Comment: Btw, note that the OP does not have the privilege to unilaterally edit tsg wikis yet, so it will likely (speaking from experience) take *a lot* of time before any wiki entry will be created (generally, it's appx. 2-4 weeks)

Comment: In general, you can remove the tag from a question if you are certain it does not make sense (e.g., it was a typo of something else) and the tag will be automatically deleted if it doesn't have any questions.

Comment: How is a tag about a specific color space "meta"? It seems to be precisely the *opposite* of "meta".

Comment: I'd say it needs to be renamed, though, before it's too late (2-3 letter tags are a primary source of ambiguous usage). Maybe to [cie-1931]? With just 1 question, it might also be easier to remove it and create a proper one

Comment: Related: the [cie] tag most likely refers to [the CIE colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space)

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray I was thinking that tagging a specific color space was too restrictive and would be better expressed in the title. But this is specifically why I asked first, to have these conversations.